# Error while trying to connect CH341 driver

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ch340

I'm trying to connect an Arduino board to IDE on Ubuntu, and I have the following driver log:

```
[  543.412356] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  549.593729] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  549.748438] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.54
[  549.748449] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  549.748454] usb 1-2: Product: USB2.0-Serial
[  549.750234] ch341 1-2:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[  549.750859] usb 1-2: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  550.347356] input: BRLTTY 6.4 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard as /devices/virtual/input/input20
[  550.462814] usb 1-2: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ch341 while 'brltty' sets config #1
[  550.463418] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[  550.463437] ch341 1-2:1.0: device disconnected
```

As a result no ports are found, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, thanks to this [article][1]

```
sudo apt autoremove brltty
```

remove the conflict and now the board is visible
[1]: https://0xsuk.github.io/posts/2022-07-19-how-to-install-ch340-on-ubuntu-22.04/